# текст не появляется

Tags: javascript

```js
function toggleText() {
  let button = document.querySelector('.toggle-text-button');
  let text = document.querySelector('#text');
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
   
    if(text.hasAttributes('hidden') == true){
       console.log('adad')
      text.hidden = '';
    }
    text.hidden = true;
  })
}

toggleText()
```

```html
<button class="toggle-text-button">Нажмите, чтобы спрятать/показать текст</button>
  <div id="text">Текст</div>
```

1. Почему не появляется текст если условие срабатывает ?

Comment: какое условие и какой текст?

Comment: Почему вы решили, что условие срабатывает?

Comment: @Эникейщик if срабатывает но текст не появляется

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский консоль выводит сообщение

Comment: Не выводит. вот смотрю в сниппет и ничего не выводит

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский  я нажимаю выполнит код выводит сообщение adad

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, условие срабатывает всегда в коде в вопросе ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ так как есть атрибут `id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

строка `text.hidden = true` выполняется **каждый** раз при нажатии кнопки, так как расположена после `if`

Для решения, эту строку нужно поместить в блок `else`.

Еще один недочет связан с использованием [`.hasAttributes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/hasAttributes), данный метод не принимает никаких параметров и возвращает `true` если у элемента есть **хотя бы один**, **любой**, атрибут.

Для проверки наличий конкретного атрибута, нужно использовать метод [`.hasAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/hasAttribute)

```js
function toggleText() {
  let button = document.querySelector('.toggle-text-button');
  let text = document.querySelector('#text');
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (text.hasAttribute('hidden') == true) {
      console.log('adad')
      text.hidden = '';
    } else {
      text.hidden = true;
    }
  })
}

toggleText()
```

```html
<button class="toggle-text-button">Нажмите, чтобы спрятать/показать текст</button>
<div id="text">Текст</div>
```

Comment: Брррррррр, атрибуты.

Comment: @Qwertiy, что не так?

Comment: Использование атрибутов вместо свойств. Хотя с hidden это хотя бы работает.

Answer (score 2):

Может так будет лучше?
*Почему не появляется текст если условие срабатывает ?*
Потому-что у вас после выполнение условия которая в `if` выполняется `text.hidden = true` которая скрывает текст занова

```js
const button = document.querySelector('.toggle-text-button');
const text = document.querySelector('#text');

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  text.classList.toggle('hide');
})
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button class="toggle-text-button">Нажмите, чтобы спрятать/показать текст</button>
<div id="text">Текст</div>
```

Это для вас будет работать

```js
function toggleText() {
  let button = document.querySelector('.toggle-text-button');
  let text = document.querySelector('#text');
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {

    if (text.hidden == true) {
      console.log('adad')
      text.hidden = '';
    } else text.hidden = true;
  })
}

toggleText()
```

```html
<button class="toggle-text-button">Нажмите, чтобы спрятать/показать текст</button>
<div id="text">Текст</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Делать надо так:

```js
function toggleText() {
  let button = document.querySelector('.toggle-text-button');
  let text = document.querySelector('#text');

  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    text.hidden = !text.hidden;
  })
}

toggleText()
```

```html
<button class="toggle-text-button">Нажмите, чтобы спрятать/показать текст</button>
<div id="text">Текст</div>
```

Ну или так, если там ещё что-то сделать надо:

```js
function toggleText() {
  let button = document.querySelector('.toggle-text-button');
  let text = document.querySelector('#text');

  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let isHidden = text.hidden
  
    if (isHidden) {
      console.log('adad')
    }
    
    text.hidden = !isHidden;
  })
}

toggleText()
```

```html
<button class="toggle-text-button">Нажмите, чтобы спрятать/показать текст</button>
<div id="text">Текст</div>
```